# The best methods for multivariate polynomial equations over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, groebner-basis, multivariate-polynomial, resultant

I am trying to get a rough overview of the best methods one might use to find solutions of multivariate polynomial equations over large finite fields. We can suppose for simplicity that the given system has a finite number of solutions (over the closure).

As I understand it, the general algebraic methods for finding solutions over *rational* numbers are either based on the Grobner basis (computing the elimination ideal) or are based on the resultants. **First question**: Are there any other general algebraic methods?

**Second (main) question**: Is the situation over finite fields any different? Are there any other general methods which only work for finite fields?

To maybe illustrate my confusion from all the sources I have been going through:
The figure on page 3 of this [thesis on finite field multivariate polynomial equations](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01110887/document) is trying to give the reader some rough overview. But it doesn't include any resultant-based methods. Are these not suitable for finite fields for some reason I am not seeing?

Any answers or sources to answers would be very appreciated.